# Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, security, supee-6788, routing

If I enable Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions Magento states that security of the admin would be weaken.

http://prntscr.com/8z9rqx

Please could someone explain exactly how it would be weaken? I have an instance where I have 20+ extensions which need this enabled to trying to figure out exactly what the security risks are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compatibility mode is related to **APPSEC-1034, addressing bypassing custom admin URL**

From the SUPEE-6788 patch detail page:

> Admin Path Disclosure - APPSEC-1034
>
> CVSSv3 Severity: 5.3 (Medium)
>
> Attacker can force showing admin panel login page regardless of admin
> panel URL by calling a module directly. It makes it easier to try
> automated password attacks and exposes admin URL on the page.

The best way is to **update** the extensions and disable compatibility mode:

1.) All reliable extension vendors updated their extensions so you just have to look for the latest releases.

2.) Update your own extensions with the information from the [technical details page](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

See also here:

- https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788
- https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Comment: Thanks for your reply, exactly what I wanted to know. My question after reading that is if I have other protection against automated attacks eg Recaptcha (http://prntscr.com/9ossms) does it really matter if I have this enabled